# HTTP Status 404 Error - [Message] The requested resource [/DentalRecordFYP/updateInvent] is not available

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have this error and I can't seem to fix it. The java file is supposed to update the new details of the item to the database table "inventory". While the jsp file is where you do the adjustment. Please assist me in this issue

This is the JSP file where the details can be edited.

```
<section>
        <div class="main">
            <div class="container-contact100">
                <div class="wrap-contact100">
                    <div class="contact100-form-title"
                        style="background-image: url(img/bg-01.jpg);">
                        <span class="contact100-form-title-1"> Item Details </span>
                    </div>

                    <form class="contact100-form validate-form" action="updateInvent"
                        method="post" id="register-form">

                        <div class="hiddeninfo">
                            <label for="name"><i
                                class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label> <input
                                type="text" name="id" id="id" value=<%=rs.getString(1)%> />
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input"
                            data-validate="Item Name is required">
                            <span class="label-input100"><i
                                class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></span> <input
                                class="input100" type="text" name="itemname" id="itemname"
                                value=<%=rs.getString(2)%> > <span
                                class="focus-input100"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input"
                            data-validate="Item status is required">
                            <span class="label-input100"><i class="zmdi zmdi-status"></i></span>
                            <input class="input100" type="itemstatus" name="itemstatus" id="itemstatus"
                                value=<%=rs.getString(3)%> > <span
                                class="focus-input100"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input"
                            data-validate="Item quantity is required">
                            <span class="label-input100"><i class="zmdi zmdi-quantity"></i></span>
                            <input class="input100" type="text" name="itemqty" id="itemqty"
                                value=<%=rs.getString(4)%> >
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="wrap-input100 validate-input"
                            data-validate="Date of Birth is required">
                            <span class="label-input100"><i class="zmdi zmdi-calendar"></i></span>
                            <input class="input100" type="date" name="itemexpdate" id="itemexpdate"
                                value=<%=rs.getString(5)%> >
                            <span class="focus-input100"></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
                            <button class="contact100-form-btn btn-updateInvent">
                                <span> Update </span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    <form method="post" action="delete"
                        class="contact100-form validate-form small-form" id="register-form">
                        <div class="hiddeninfo">
                            <label for="name"> <i
                                class="zmdi zmdi-account material-icons-name"></i></label> <input
                                type="text" name="id" id="id" value=<%=rs.getString(1)%> />
                        </div>
                        <div class="container-contact100-form-btn">
                            <button class="btn-danger">
                                <span> Delete </span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Where this is the java file where it update the new data that was edited in the JSP and replace the new data to the database table accordingly

```
@WebServlet("/updateInvent")
public class UpdateInventory extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public UpdateInventory() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String id = request.getParameter("id");     
        String itemname = request.getParameter("itemname");
        String itemstatus = request.getParameter("itemstatus");
        String itemqty = request.getParameter("itemqty");
        String itemexpdate = request.getParameter("itemexpdate");
        Connection conn = null;
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dentalrecord?useSSL=false","root","");
            PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE inventory set itemname=?,itemstatus=?,itemqty=?,itemexpdate=?");
            pst.setString(1, itemname);
            pst.setString(2, itemstatus);
            pst.setString(3, itemqty);
            pst.setString(4, itemexpdate);
            pst.executeUpdate();
            response.sendRedirect("inventorylist.jsp");
        }
        catch(IllegalStateException ignore) {
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            try {
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I see your Servlet is declaring the path @WebServlet("/update"), and the error is related to a different path: /DentalRecordFYP/updateInvent

Comment: @cdr89 sorry i've just edited it, please take a look again and let me know wheres the issue at

Comment: there is stil the " /DentalRecordFYP" at the beginning of the path, where this come from? Could you please share where this is configured? Have you tried to invoke your servlet just on /updateInvent without the prefix?